# I need assistance in fixing this bug in node

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node and I keep getting this error every time I try to access a file from the command line.

```
   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

   Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ngs\1-getting-started1- 
    executing-scripts1-hello-world.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Can you please give more context? Code sample, etc?

Comment: I was only trying to access a file I cloned on github from the command line. I used the command $ node "file -path". and  that was the error that was returned.

Comment: Are you just trying to run arbitrary files from a node project individually?

Answer (score -1):

I am supposing you are working with this [repo](https://github.com/jscomplete/ngs). 
Do a git clone of that 
cd to the directory C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ngs1-getting-started\1-executing-scripts. Then type in "node 1-hello-world.js"
Open up a browser to localhost:4242

Comment: Thanks for your response. I deleted the repo and recloned then used npm install. I got a message to try npm audit.

Comment: npm audit fix
npm WARN desktop@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN desktop@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 0.817s
fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 189 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated

Comment: Try just npm install?